# Enable samba local master on 22.04.1?

Tags: server, samba

Is there some new option I need to set to make local master work like it did in 18.04?
22.04 samba version

I am trying to upgrade two of my “servers” from 18.04.6 (desktop) to 22.04.1.
In 18.04 I set

local master = yes

and

preferred master = no

in smb.conf

I also disabled local master (in the registry) of all Windows PCs.

If only one server was running it would become the master and would continue to be master when I started the second server.
If I shut down the “master” the other server would automatically assume the master function.

A server running 22.04.1 with the same settings will not assume the master function even if it there is no local master.

However, if I have a server on 22.04.1 running it also prevents a server running 18.04 from assuming the master function.

I tried setting the OS level to both 40 and 65 – no help.
I tried removing “preferred master = no” – no help.

Comment: Have you enabled SMB1 on the server? All these old time local master, workgroup, even netbios itself settings will not work without it and the version of samba you are using in Ubuntu 22.04 disables it. You might want to add to the [global] section of smb.conf `server min protocol = NT1` Since samba likes to spawn several instances of smbd / nmbd you likely will need a reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much - that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Morbius1

server min protocol = NT1

fixed my problem